# Can't get Facebook Email to login with facebook by inchoo

Tags: facebook, magento, authentication

I use login by facebook from inchoo [Inchoo login with facebook](http://inchoo.net/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/)

but i can't get email to register with facebook

how can i get email from facebook?

PS. i try to check log api version is 2.0 where i can change it

data to check log

```
$client = self::_getHttpClient()
            ->setUri($url) 
            ->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST)
            ->resetParameters()
            ->setRawData($params);
```

> [Facebook-api-version] => v2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can get email from facebook now in AccountController.php line 86

change from

```
$standardInfo = $this->_getSession()->getClient()->call("/me");
```

to

```
$standardInfo = $this->_getSession()->getClient()->call("/me?fields=id,name,email");
```

now you can get email to register with facebook

Comment: Accept your answer to *close* the question :)

Comment: i can't accept because 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'